# Is it possible to find inverse function with mathjs ?

Tags: node.js, mathjs

Because I couldn't find any answer on documentation... 
His there a way to find math inverse function with mathjs or Nodejs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this functionality is not yet implemented. However, the mathjs team is working hard to make this a reality in the near future.